# java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent

Tags: android, material-design, android-version, material-components-android

I added compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1' for my project for recent material support getting ClassCastException. My target and compile sdk version is 28.

All the activity with getActionBar throws this exception. Also app theme with action bar in it throws the error.
Using this theme for activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

My detailed crash log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{...../com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:414)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                             at
>   com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity.onCreate(CropImageActivity.java:63)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Can you post what you have at that line 
 - `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)`, and the lines around it? It looks like you are trying to make a cast that is not allowed.

Comment: that wiil be package name of the application

Comment: Does your `CropImageActivity` extend anything?

Comment: Thank you all. I resolved it by changing theme of my activity